What is $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {\ln x}{{({1-x+x^2})}^2} \rm{d}x$?
What is $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {\ln x}{{({1-x+x^2})}^2} \rm{d}x$ ?

I m not getting any idea for this one . Expecting from the community to share some interesting substitution ideas / tricks .

My try :
Let $I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {\ln x}{{({1-x+x^2})}^2} \rm{d}x$ .
Putting $x = \frac {1}{u}$, $I$ becomes
$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {-u^2\ln u}{{({1-u+u^2})}^2} \rm{d}u$ which is equivalent to $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {-x^2\ln x}{{({1-x+x^2})}^2} \rm{d}x$ which on further manipulating the two forms of it wasn't any much helpful . Also trying $x = e^t$ substitution didn't work . So any better ideas ?

Is the square on the entire expression ? @Ash_Blanc

Integrate[(Log[x]/(1 - x + x^2))^2, {x, 0, Infinity}]  $\int_0^{\infty } \left(\frac{\log (x)}{x^2-x+1}\right)^2 , dx= \frac{1}{729} \pi ^2 \left(40 \sqrt{3} \pi -27\right)$

@Sam sorry the square is on denominator only

If you can edit the question to show your work, we can vote to reopen the question. @Ash_Blanc

@Sam thanx for responding though

Hint: use a keyhole contour, but counterintuitively you need to integrate $\frac{\ln^\color{blue}{2}z}{(1-z+z^2)^2}$ around it. It's a more complicated version of this technique.

It can also be solved by use of Feynmann trick.

Let $ x\to 1/x$
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {\ln x}{{({1-x+x^2})}^2} dx\\
=&-\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {x^2\ln x}{{({1-x+x^2})}^2} dx
= \frac12\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {(1-x^2)\ln x}{{({1-x+x^2})}^2} dx\\
=&\ \frac12\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln x \ d\bigg( \frac { x}{{{1-x+x^2}}} \bigg)
= -\frac12\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac { 1}{{{1-x+x^2}}} dx =-\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt3}\\
\end{align}

@ShyamalSayak it is integration by parts

Lovely observation of differential of $\frac{x}{1-x+x^2}$ I wonder why the idea didn't click on my mind even seeing that square in the denominator
